# Can JMeter support to send HTTP1.1's pipeline requests?

Tags: http, jmeter, pipeline

I was using JMeter for several years.
But recently I need to send HTTP1.1 request with pipelining from JMeter to my server.
We know, pipeline feature allows client(or web browser) send more than one http requests(GET) in once sending.
I went through the help doc of JMeter and couldn't find any clue.
I know the business test instrument like Spirent has this kind of feature.
But I have only JMeter.
any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No for HttpClient based implementations as they do not implement it:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPASYNC-8

No as per Java impl.

You can open an enhacement request at Bugzilla

Comment: thanks for accept, you can also upvote if it's fine for you:)